# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing Class with Struts2 and QuartzSchedulerListener

Tags: java, class, struts2, scheduler, quartz

I have a project with Quartz working perfectly, and now, I am doing another one, but it gets me a extrange error that I have not solved by myself.

The trace is.

```
 *GRAVE: Excepcion enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase com.is.pr.timer.QuartzSchedulerListener
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoade
r.java:2818)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1
148)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1
643)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1
521)
        at com.is.pr.timer.QuartzSchedulerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzSchedulerListe
ner.java:25)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:470
1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)*
```

And the line it gets the error.

```
public class QuartzSchedulerListener implements ServletContextListener {

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    //
}

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(CheckStates.class)
        .withIdentity("anyJobName", "group1").build();

    try {

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
          .newTrigger()
          .withIdentity("anyTriggerName", "group1")
          .withSchedule(
             CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/70 * * * * ?"))
          .build();

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In my web.xml y added as well:

```
<listener>
      <listener-class>
            com.is.pr.timer.QuartzSchedulerListener
      </listener-class>
</listener>
```

I have the libraries included of course:

```
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
quartz-2.2.3.jar
quartz-all-2.1.5.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7-jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar
```

But nothing works. And I copied the same from my other running project, what am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The first one I put.

Comment: *GRAVE: Excepcion enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase com.is.pr.timer.QuartzSchedulerListener
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Answer (score -3):

Solved. It was because I had an old library in lib folder: I removed it and it works.